# Melt using patterns when variable names contain string information - avoid coercion to numeric

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I am using the `patterns()` argument in `data.table::melt()` to melt data that has columns that have several easily-defined patterns. It is working, but I'm not seeing how I can create a character index variable instead of the default numeric breakdown.

For example, in data set 'A', the dog and cat column names have numeric suffixes (e.g. 'dog_1', 'cat_2'), which are handled correctly in `melt` (see the resulting 'variable' column):

```
A = data.table(idcol = c(1:5),
            dog_1 = c(1:5),   cat_1 = c(101:105),
            dog_2 = c(6:10),  cat_2 = c(106:110),
            dog_3 = c(11:15), cat_3 = c(111:115))  

head(melt(A, measure = patterns("^dog", "^cat"), value.name = c("dog", "cat")))
   
   idcol variable dog cat
1:     1        1   1 101
2:     2        1   2 102
3:     3        1   3 103
4:     4        1   4 104
5:     5        1   5 105
6:     1        2   6 106
```

However, in data set 'B', the suffix of dog and cat columns is a string (e.g. 'dog_one', 'cat_two'). Such suffixes are converted to a numeric representation in `melt`, see the "variable" column.

```
B = data.table(idcol = c(1:5),
                dog_one = c(1:5),     cat_one = c(101:105),
                dog_two = c(6:10),    cat_two = c(106:110),
                dog_three = c(11:15), cat_three = c(111:115))

head(melt(B, measure = patterns("^dog", "^cat"), value.name = c("dog", "cat")))

   idcol variable dog cat
1:     1        1   1 101
2:     2        1   2 102
3:     3        1   3 103
4:     4        1   4 104
5:     5        1   5 105
6:     1        2   6 106
```

How can I fill the "variable" column with the correct string suffixes one/two/three instead of 1/2/3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From `data.table 1.14.1` (in development; [installation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation#v1141-in-development--)), the new function `measure` makes it much easier to melt data with concatenated variable names to a desired format (see `?measure`.

The `sep`arator argument is used to create different groups of `measure.vars`. In the `...` argument, we further specify the fate of the values corresponding to the groups generated by `sep`.

In OP, the variable names are of the form `species_number`, e.g. `dog_one`. Thus, we need two symbols in `...` to specify how groups *before* and *after* the `sep`arator should be treated, one for the species (dog or cat) and one for the numbers (one-three).

If a symbol in `...` is set to `value.name`, then "`melt` returns *multiple* value columns (with names defined by the unique values in that group)". Thus, because you want multiple columns for each species, the *first* group defined by the separator, the *first* symbol in `...` should be `value.name`.

The *second* group, after the separator, are the numbers, so this is specified as the second symbol in `...`. We want in a single value column for the numbers, so here we specify the desired column name of the output variable, e.g. "nr".

```
melt(B, measure.vars = measure(value.name, nr, sep = "_"))

      idcol    nr dog cat
#  1:     1   one   1 101
#  2:     2   one   2 102
#  3:     3   one   3 103
#  4:     4   one   4 104
#  5:     5   one   5 105
#  6:     1   two   6 106
#  7:     2   two   7 107
#  8:     3   two   8 108
#  9:     4   two   9 109
# 10:     5   two  10 110
# 11:     1 three  11 111
# 12:     2 three  12 112
# 13:     3 three  13 113
# 14:     4 three  14 114
# 15:     5 three  15 115
```

---

Pre `data.table 1.14.1`

There might be easier ways, but this seems to work:

```
# grab suffixes of 'variable' names
suff <- unique(sub('^.*_', '', names(B[ , -1])))
# suff <- unique(tstrsplit(names(B[, -1]), "_")[[2]])

# melt
B2 <- melt(B, measure = patterns("^dog", "^cat"), value.name = c("dog", "cat"))
   
# replace factor levels in 'variable' with the suffixes
setattr(B2$variable, "levels", suff)

B2
#     idcol variable dog cat
# 1:      1      one   1 101
# 2:      2      one   2 102
# 3:      3      one   3 103
# 4:      4      one   4 104
# 5:      5      one   5 105
# 6:      1      two   6 106
# 7:      2      two   7 107
# 8:      3      two   8 108
# 9:      4      two   9 109
# 10:     5      two  10 110
# 11:     1    three  11 111
# 12:     2    three  12 112
# 13:     3    three  13 113
# 14:     4    three  14 114
# 15:     5    three  15 115
```

Two related `data.table` issues:

[melt.data.table should offer `variable` to match on the name, rather than the number](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3396)

[FR: expansion of melt functionality for handling names of output](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1547).

---

This is one of the (rare) instances where I believe good'ol `base::reshape` is cleaner. Its `sep` argument comes in handy here — both the names of the 'value' column and the levels of the 'variable' columns are generated in one go:

```
reshape(data = B,
        varying = names(B[ , -1]),
        sep = "_",
        direction = "long")
```

Comment: yes, the variable col. levels needs to be constructed manually still.. Thumbs up for base::reshape.

Comment: The github issue link is super helpful!

Comment: @Nancy I just wanted to let you know that I have updated the answer with the new function `measure`, available from `data.table 1.14.1`.