# Using melt() function from data.table for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data.table, transformation, melt, long-format-data

I have a composite score (BASFI) which consists of components Q1-Q10 and a bunch of variables I want unchanged. I wanted to go from a wide format to a long format. The composite score and components have been measured at 4 time points. Please see dataset for more details on this.

Reproducible dataset:

```
structure(list(composite_baseline = c(40, NA, 16), composite_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), composite_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), composite_24month = c(NA, 
12, NA), q1_socks_baseline = c(0, NA, 0), q1_socks_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q1_socks_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q1_socks_24month = c(NA, 
20, NA), q2_pen_baseline = c(0, NA, 20), q2_pen_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q2_pen_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q2_pen_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q3_shelf_baseline = c(10, NA, 40), q3_shelf_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q3_shelf_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q3_shelf_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q4_chair_baseline = c(30, NA, 10), q4_chair_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q4_chair_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q4_chair_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q5_floor_baseline = c(50, NA, 20), q5_floor_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q5_floor_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q5_floor_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q6_standing_baseline = c(30, NA, 0), q6_standing_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q6_standing_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q6_standing_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q7_steps_baseline = c(70, NA, 10), q7_steps_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q7_steps_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q7_steps_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q8_shoulder_baseline = c(50, NA, 0), q8_shoulder_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q8_shoulder_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q8_shoulder_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), q9_activities_baseline = c(70, NA, 30), q9_activities_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q9_activities_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q9_activities_24month = c(NA, 
20, NA), q10_day_baseline = c(90, NA, 30), q10_day_6month = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), q10_day_12month = c(NA, 0, NA), q10_day_24month = c(NA, 
10, NA), age_at_diagnosis = c(31, 38, 34), hla_b27 = c("pos", 
"neg", "neg"), years_since_symptoms_onset = c(25L, 3L, 4L), smoking_status = c("never", 
"past", "past"), bio_drug_name = c("golimumab", "adalimumab", 
"golimumab"), bmi = c(25.7629805786762, 24.3910588392529, 21.9713358572201
), nsaid_baseline = c("0", NA, "1"), concom_csdmard_baseline = c(1, 
1, 0), bio_drug_start_year = c(2011L, 2007L, 2011L), country = c("CH", 
"CH", "CH"), asas_criteria_3_enthesitis = c(1L, 0L, 1L), asas_criteria_2_arthritis = c(1L, 
1L, 0L), asas_criteria_6_psoriasis = c(0L, 0L, 0L), asas_criteria_7_ibd = c(0L, 
1L, 0L), asas_criteria_4_uveitis = c(0L, 0L, 0L), crp_baseline = c(11, 
NA, 7), gender = c("female", "male", "female"), ID = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Looks like this

```
   composite_baseline composite_6month composite_12month composite_24month q1_socks_baseline q1_socks_6month q1_socks_12month q1_socks_24month
1:                 40               NA                NA                NA                 0              NA               NA               NA
2:                 NA               NA                 0                12                NA              NA                0               20
3:                 16               NA                NA                NA                 0              NA               NA               NA
   q2_pen_baseline q2_pen_6month q2_pen_12month q2_pen_24month q3_shelf_baseline q3_shelf_6month q3_shelf_12month q3_shelf_24month q4_chair_baseline
1:               0            NA             NA             NA                10              NA               NA               NA                30
2:              NA            NA              0             10                NA              NA                0               10                NA
3:              20            NA             NA             NA                40              NA               NA               NA                10
   q4_chair_6month q4_chair_12month q4_chair_24month q5_floor_baseline q5_floor_6month q5_floor_12month q5_floor_24month q6_standing_baseline
1:              NA               NA               NA                50              NA               NA               NA                   30
2:              NA                0               10                NA              NA                0               10                   NA
3:              NA               NA               NA                20              NA               NA               NA                    0
   q6_standing_6month q6_standing_12month q6_standing_24month q7_steps_baseline q7_steps_6month q7_steps_12month q7_steps_24month q8_shoulder_baseline
1:                 NA                  NA                  NA                70              NA               NA               NA                   50
2:                 NA                   0                  10                NA              NA                0               10                   NA
3:                 NA                  NA                  NA                10              NA               NA               NA                    0
   q8_shoulder_6month q8_shoulder_12month q8_shoulder_24month q9_activities_baseline q9_activities_6month q9_activities_12month q9_activities_24month
1:                 NA                  NA                  NA                     70                   NA                    NA                    NA
2:                 NA                   0                  10                     NA                   NA                     0                    20
3:                 NA                  NA                  NA                     30                   NA                    NA                    NA
   q10_day_baseline q10_day_6month q10_day_12month q10_day_24month age_at_diagnosis hla_b27 years_since_symptoms_onset smoking_status bio_drug_name
1:               90             NA              NA              NA               31     pos                         25          never     golimumab
2:               NA             NA               0              10               38     neg                          3           past    adalimumab
3:               30             NA              NA              NA               34     neg                          4           past     golimumab
        bmi nsaid_baseline concom_csdmard_baseline bio_drug_start_year country asas_criteria_3_enthesitis asas_criteria_2_arthritis
1: 25.76298              0                       1                2011      CH                          1                         1
2: 24.39106           <NA>                       1                2007      CH                          0                         1
3: 21.97134              1                       0                2011      CH                          1                         0
   asas_criteria_6_psoriasis asas_criteria_7_ibd asas_criteria_4_uveitis crp_baseline gender ID
1:                         0                   0                       0           11 female  1
2:                         0                   1                       0           NA   male  2
3:                         0                   0                       0            7 female  3
```

Code I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
dat_long <- melt(setDT(dat), id.vars = 45:62,
                 measure=c("composite", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10"), 
                 value.name=c("basfi_composite", "basfi_1_socks", "basfi_2_pen", "basfi_3_shelf", "basfi_4_chair", 
                              "basfi_5_floor", "basfi_6_standing", "basfi_7_steps", "basfi_8_shoulder", "basfi_9_activities_demanding", "basfi_10_activities_day"))
```

**Basically gives 24 observations when 12 were expected (4 time points * 3 observations).**

Comment: What is `id_vars`? What exactly are the columns you're expecting out?

Comment: @r2evans I adjusted the code. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is somewhat complicated by the fact that time and measure are separated by "_" but some measures also have "_" in their names.

Also, unfortunately melt does not support names_sep like `pivot_longer` and when you melt in multiple columns, the melted variables are given an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45202066/6912817) instead of a name

First, i melt all in one column into a temporary DT to obtain variable names. Then, by using strsplit and a lookbehind in the regexp (to avoid the underscore in q1..10 names) i create the measure and time variable.

```r
tmp <- melt(setDT(dat) , id.vars = names(dat)[!grepl("^q\\d|composite", names(dat))],
            variable.factor = FALSE) 
tmp[, c("variable", "time") := as.data.table(
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(variable, "(?<!\\d)_", perl=T)))]
```

Finally you can dcast the result to get the 12 variables (plus the id vars)

```
dcast(tmp, ... ~  time + ID, value.var = "value" )
```

Comment: Regarding "_Also, unfortunately melt does not support names_sep like pivot_longer and when you melt in multiple columns, the melted variables are given an index instead of a name_", see e.g. [Melt using patterns when variable names contain string information - avoid coercion to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883573/melt-using-patterns-when-variable-names-contain-string-information-avoid-coerc/41884029#41884029)