# pivot_longer gives error when using dtplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dtplyr

I have a large dataset I'm trying to tidy using dtplyr. It consists of a large number (>1000) of date-value pairs for various locations. The original uses a pivot_longer, which works fine in dplyr, but gives an error in dtplyr. Is there a way to fix this, maintaining the performance benefits of dtplyr?

This works

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)

my_data_tb <- tribble(
  ~`date-A`, ~`value-A`, ~`date-B`, ~`value-B`,
  "date1", 1, "date2", 2,
  "date2", 1, "date3", 2 
)

my_data_tb %>% 
  pivot_longer(
  cols = everything(),
  names_to = c(".value", "grid_square"),
  names_sep = "-"
)
```

but this gives the error:

```
my_data_dt <- as.data.table(my_data_tb)
my_data_dt <- lazy_dt(my_data_dt)

my_data_dt %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "grid_square"),
    names_sep = "-"
  )
```

The error message is:

> Error: Can't subset elements that don't exist.
> x The locations 1 and 2 don't exist.
> i There are only 0 elements.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> In addition: Warning message:
> Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 7 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. 
> `rlang::last_error()`
> Error: Internal error: Trace data is not square.

UPDATE - it now gives this error message:

> Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") :
> no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "c('dtplyr_step_first', 'dtplyr_step')"

As an aside, this also works, but I think it loses the dtplyr performance gain:

```
my_data_dt %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "grid_square"),
    names_sep = "-"
  )
```

Comment: Just a thought: `pivot_longer` being a `tidyr` verb, not a `dplyr` one, that could explain why it's not been translated.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I hadn't realised that! In which case I probably need a `data.table` solution. From the looks of this: [name-variables-during-multiple-melt-with-data-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435780/name-variables-during-multiple-melt-with-data-table) there isn't a perfect answer - that points back to `pivot_longer` which doesn't work in this situation!

Comment: This should get you close: `melt(
  as.data.table(my_data_tb),
  variable.name = "grid_square",
  measure.vars = patterns(date = "^date-", value = "^value-")
)`, but yes, there is the open issue of  `A`, `B` being lost to level indices, though it's an easy fix a posteriori

Comment: Thanks, that's great. For completeness I have:
`#melt`  
`my_data_dt <- my_data_dt %>%`  
`as.data.table() %>% `  
`melt.data.table(measure = patterns("^date-", "^value-"), value.name = c("date", "value"))`  

`# Fix variable names (conveniently I already have a list of variable names from an `  
`# earlier step in my script`  
`v_names <- c("A", "B")`  
`my_data_dt$variable <- v_names[my_data_dt$variable]`

Comment: You may also have a look at: https://github.com/markfairbanks/tidytable/ and https://github.com/TysonStanley/tidyfast (not tested myself), they attempt to close that tidyr - data.table gap

Comment: There is now an open issue to add `tidyr` methods to `dtplyr`, which will include `pivot_longer()`

Comment: Link to open issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/168

Comment: `pivot_longer()` is now included in the development version of `dtplyr`, which can be installed using `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dtplyr")`. This should work when [v1.2.0 is released](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/302) (I haven't tested the development version on this issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dtplyr version 1.2.0 is now available on CRAN, which means this issue is now resolved!

For anyone experiencing this error, check/update your version of dtplyr to ensure you are running >=1.2.0:

```
install.packages("dtplyr")
```

(NB. this isn't updated as part of the tidyverse packages so make sure to do it separately)

https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/12/dtplyr-1-2-0/

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtplyr/index.html